# Divide an image into equal sized blocks using MATLAB and use Gabor filter

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, block

How to divide a facial image of size 120x120 into 64 blocks of 15x15 pixel size using MATLAB? Then I want to convolve each 15x15 block with Gabor filter.  I failed in using the blkproc function.How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To extract these blocks you can use the following, assuming `img` is a 120x120 image matrix, `c=15`, `w=8`:

```
blocks = reshape(permute(reshape(img, c, w, c, w), [1 3 2 4]), c, c, w * w)
```

Now `blocks` is a 15x15x64 matrix, and `blocks(:, :, i)` is a 15x15 matrix representing the `i`-th block.

Comment: Thanks.Before getting your answer itself I used the following to get what i wanted :'B=mat2cell(y,[15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15],[15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15])' Then i used a for loop to get the blocks.

Comment: MATLAB is all about matrix computations and multi-dimensional data manipulation. So make the `reshape` and the `permute` your friends.